# Template for custom content type

Tags: theming, nodes, entities, 8

I created a module which creates a content type called **equipment**. Which includes multiple fields and a field collection. But now I want to style the template with those fields. As suggested from the HTML comments thanks to the Twig debugging, I created a file called **node--equipment.html.twig** which is located inside the **templates** folder of the module. Unfortunately this template won't show up, so it shows the default template.

Doesn't Drupal 8 recognize the Twig file? What is the reason for not showing the wanted template? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

To recognize a suggestion in a module, you need to explicitly specify it in hook_theme() of your module.

`system_theme()` for example has this:

```
// Normally theme suggestion templates are only picked up when they are in
// themes. We explicitly define theme suggestions here so that the block
// templates in core/modules/system/templates are picked up.
'block__system_branding_block' => array(
  'render element' => 'elements',
  'base hook' => 'block',
),
```

Copy the original definition and then change the key and set the base hook.

Comment: What about the variables (fields I applied to the content type)? Do I need to specify those inside of the suggestion?

Comment: And the path of the template file inside of the module?

Comment: You need the same definition as defined in node_theme(), it use a render element, not variables. Apparently it works fine for system.module without a path, maybe it defaults to the templates folder.

Comment: You are right you don't need the path. Drupal automatically looks for the template inside of the templates folder. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I finally fixed the problem. As Berdir said, to recognize a template you need to explicitly specify a suggestion in the `hook_theme()` implementation of the module. My `hook_theme()` looks like this:

```
function equipment_theme(array $variables) {
  $theme = array();

  # Suggestion for the template
  $theme['node__equipment'] = array(
      'render element' => 'content',
      'base hook' => 'node',
      # template file
      'template' => 'node--equipment',
      # location of the template file
     'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'equipment') . '/templates',
  );

  return $theme;
}
```